# setTimeout not compatible with localStorage API(getItem/setItem)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am so curious why these two codes behave differently? Functions like 'console.log' would work in both ways, while localStorage API functions(getItem,setItem) does not work.

```
setTimeout(()=>localStorage.setItem('1','2'),1000)
// setTimeout(code, delay) works

setTimeout(localStorage.setItem,1000,'1','2')
// setTimeout(functionRef, delay, param1) not working, error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"
```

But according to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout),these two formats should both work. Thank you.

What is the logic behind it? Could you please share something with me? Thank you so so much :)

Comment: They both don't work because in the second one you have broken `localeStorage` binding,  IOW:: The full stop after localStorage to bind the call is not there.   But you can get it back ->  `setTimeout(localStorage.setItem.bind(localStorage),1000,'1','2')`

Comment: Thank you so much. @Keith. You are right! 'thisArg' which is 'localStorage' is lost in the second case, I need to bind a 'this' to the function. (the first actually works)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, when I said both don't work, I meant that one of them not working.

Comment: Thank you again, Keith. Have a great week! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Keith, `setTimeout(localStorage.setItem,1000,'1','2')` is actually equal to `setTimeout(functon(){...this...},1000,'1','2')`, while 'this' was lost when the function 'localStorage.setItem' was called separately. So we need to bind 'this' back to the function.

```
setTimeout(localStorage.setItem.bind(localStorage),1000,'1','2')
```